# Drive P-mos with N-mos for large voltage range

Tags: mosfet

I'd like to be able to drive a large panel of lights with a P-mos (I need to drive on the high side because some lights have a common ground and needs to be drived independantly).

I'd like to use :

- a LBSS123 N-MOS
  https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/MOSFETs_LRC-LBSS123LT1G_C8491.html
- a AO4421 P-MOS
  https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Others_Alpha-Omega-Semicon_AO4421_Alpha-Omega-Semicon-AOS-AO4421_C33484.html

... because I already have the components

I need from 2A max in 5V to 1A at 55V output with a very slow commutation rate (1Hz max).

The difficulty is to be able to handle a large range of voltage from 5 to 55V.

The command will be a 3.3V IO from a MCU.

The circuit I designed is this :

[image]

I am not sure it can handle 5V input...

Can anybody help ?

Datasheet links:

[LBSS123](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1810221412_LRC-LBSS123LT1G_C8491.pdf)

[AO4421](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Others_Alpha-Omega-Semicon_AO4421_Alpha-Omega-Semicon-AOS-AO4421_C33484.html)

EDIT : wrong mosfet spec posted.

Comment: I'm more concerned about the gate to source voltage of that AO4419 when you turn it on.

Comment: How is your load (lights) handling so wide range of input voltages? Does it include any step-down converter? Or anything else. Does the 2 A max current apply for 5V (and scales down with increasing input voltage)? Or anything else?

Comment: yes, from 5V 2A to 60V 1A output.

Comment: it will mostly be various LED lights

Comment: it was the wrong mosfet spec. I'd like to use AO4421. (edit posted)

Answer (score 5):

Driving a p-MOSFET using resistive pull-up and low side switch generally works. You should always double-check transition time with such weak gate-drive and that the MOSFET won't be thermally damaged (but 1k pull-up looks safe-ly low).

In practice any MOSFET you can easily find will be limited to 20 V gate-source and it is good to stay around 10 V in order to not stress gate unnecessarily. So your circuit as-is won't work because you are exposing gate to the full input voltage. To handle this, you need a voltage divider, easiest done with zener diode as shown (approximately) below. Note that particular resistor values will be a compromise to provide enough gate voltage with 5V input (R1/R2 ratio), to not thermally overload ZD (D1) at highest input voltage (current is controlled by R2) and to provide fast enough gate discharge when switching off (R1). It can happen that this simple circuit can not be made to work for your range of inputs.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkq4t1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Your another problem is Vds limit of your selected pMOS -- it is only 30 V, so you can not apply 60 V over it in switch-off state. But you should be able to find another MOSFET handling higher Vds without problem. Be sure to verify that it has low enough Rds_on with 5V input.

Additional note: for the low-side switch, you can be better off using a bipolar transistor than MOSFET. Control by 3V-ish signal will be close to (if not below) gate threshold voltage for most high-voltage rated MOSFETs. Your selected nMOS should be nevertheless able to pull low drain currents down to such voltage, even if with very small marginal.

Comment: A caveat (that's not relevant here): "it's good to stay around 10 V" for the gate to source voltage isn't always true. Check the MOSFET specifications; some logic-level FETs can only survive 8 V, and many SiC FETs *require* 15 to 20 V to be fully enhanced.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. yes, I pasted the wrong reference. I'll use a AO4421 (60V).

Comment: after your comments, I revisited the specs.

with this, I think Vgs is protected from going higher than 10V (20V max for the AO4421).

at 5V, Vgs is still 3.3V. which seems acceptable for a low current output, no ?

at 60V, Vgs is limited by the zener to 10V. The diode get ~100mW, which seems acceptable, no ?

i guess my simulation is bad, because in 5v, I only get 57mA going into the load (and 800mA at 60V)... or there is still something I don't understand.
[Mosfet Vgs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ot9mB.png)
[New schematics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Vp0M.png)

Answer (score 2):

Add these relative high voltages of up to 60 V the PFET needs protection against accidential turn on via the internal Miller capacitance. If the FET is off, the leakage current will establish the 60 V at the drain terminal.

If you now connect a load, the drain voltage drops very fast to zero. This falling edge reaches the gate via Cdg and can turn on the FET. The impedance of R1 is too high to discharge the gate in time. The result sometimes is heavy oscillation and a dead FET.

To compensate this I added C1 in my circuit. Its value is large compared to Cdg and the FET will stay off while connecting a load.

I wanted to limit the power dissipation in the zener diode and the resistor R2. I implemented a current mirror circuit with Q1 and Q2. The current via R4 coming from 3.3 V is mirrored into R2, more or less independent of the supply voltage.

With this trick the PFET gate voltage will be optimal at 5 V supply and at 60 V supply and the current through R2 always is below 1.3 mA.

Q1 and Q2 need thermal coupling to avoid current regulation issues.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3k15j.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>